# ggplot2 Unable to fill histogram with color by column

Tags: r, ggplot2

So, I am trying to compare count of a variable by frequency of another, so I have

```
ggplot(data = Q11b) +
 geom_histogram(mapping = aes(x = WEIGHT2, fill = EDUCA), binwidth = 5)
```

In this, WEIGHT2 is continuous, and what I'm trying to have the fill based on 'EDUCA', which is a column of number 1-6. So, I am expecting the histogram to show a plot of the distribution with 6 colors in a legends, like I've seen in many examples.
Instead, I get this:

[image]

Do you guys have any idea where I went wrong? I tried a geom_freqpoly() and had the same issue. I also tried changing the EDUCA part to a different column and couldn't see what I was doing wrong.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, fill=Species)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=0.05)` works, so your premise seems legitimate. It must be something different with the data. (Might also want to explicitly stack or dodge the position of each bar in that hist.)

Comment: Likely that EDUCA is a numeric variable, and it needs to be set to factor, using `as.factor()`

Comment: ggplot should also warn when numeric is used for grouping (i.e for discerte fills), something like: *Did you forget to specify a `group` aesthetic or to convert a numerical variable into a factor?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following data set should approximate yours according to your description:

```r
set.seed(1)

Q11b <- subset(data.frame(WEIGHT2 = rgamma(1e5, 3) * 20 + 100,
                          EDUCA = sample(6, 1e5, TRUE)), WEIGHT2 < 320)
```

And we get a similar result using your code (as well as a warning being emitted):

```r
library(ggplot2) 

ggplot(data = Q11b) +
  geom_histogram(mapping = aes(x = WEIGHT2, fill = EDUCA), binwidth = 5)
#> Warning: The following aesthetics were dropped during statistical transformation: fill
#> i This can happen when ggplot fails to infer the correct grouping structure in
#>   the data.
#> i Did you forget to specify a `group` aesthetic or to convert a numerical
#>   variable into a factor?
```

[image]

If we simply follow the advice and convert `EDUCA` to a factor, we get our colored groups:

```r
ggplot(data = Q11b) +
  geom_histogram(mapping = aes(x = WEIGHT2, fill = factor(EDUCA)), binwidth = 5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any idea why I didn't get the same warning? Just for the future, I'd love to make sure I can solve more problems, but I was getting no warning

Comment: @Lutema do you have the most up-to-date version of ggplot?